# SQL query causes error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'"

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL query, and I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'

I have checked everything, but I am unable to correct this. How can I fix it?

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), DayCheckOut, 120)
FROM
    (SELECT TOP (2)
         A1.DayCheckOut AS DayCheckOut
     FROM
         EmployeeAttendace A1
     INNER JOIN
         EmployeeMaster B1 ON A1.EmployeeId = B1.Id
     WHERE
         B1.EmailId = 'raja.xyz@gmail.com'
     ORDER BY
         A1.Id DESC)
ORDER BY
    DayCheckOut DESC
```

Comment: You need a table alias for the subquery.

Comment: Some dbms want a table alias for the sub-query. Try `...) dt order by DayCheckOut desc`.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, i give alias name and it works.

Comment: You need to add alias name for subquery like (---subquery---) as a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an alias name:

```
 SELECT top 1
 convert(varchar(19),DayCheckOut,120)
 FROM
   (SELECT top 2 A1.DayCheckOut as DayCheckOut FROM EmployeeAttendace A1 INNER JOIN
    EmployeeMaster B1 ON A1.EmployeeId = B1.Id WHERE B1.EmailId =
    'pooja.yadav@computronics.in' order by A1.Id desc) as AliasName
 order by DayCheckOut desc
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., why is that necessary? Why is *"AliasName"* not used anywhere? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51745407/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

You need an alias, let's say `q`, for the subquery `(SELECT top 2 A1.DayCheckOut as DayC ... order by A1.Id desc) q`

That's a very common problem for an *SQL Server* database.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any need for that sub-query. Modern SQL Server versions support `OFFSET`/`FETCH FIRST`.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(19),A1.DayCheckOut,120)
FROM EmployeeAttendace A1 INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster B1 ON A1.EmployeeId = B1.Id
WHERE B1.EmailId = 'raja.xyz@gmail.com'
order by A1.Id desc
offset 1 fetch next 1 row only
```

I.e., use `OFFSET` to skip the first row, and use `FETCH NEXT` to return only one row.

Answer (score 0):

It errors there, because you need an alias for a subquery.

However, you didn't need the redundant subquery:

```
SELECT top (1) convert(varchar(19),A1.DayCheckOut,120) as DayCheckOut 
        FROM EmployeeAttendace A1 
        INNER JOIN EmployeeMaster B1 ON A1.EmployeeId = B1.Id 
        WHERE B1.EmailId = 'raja.xyz@gmail.com' 
order by A1.DayCheckOut desc;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT TOP (1) convert(varchar(19),DayCheckOut,120)
FROM (SELECT TOP (2) A1.DayCheckOut as DayCheckOut
      FROM EmployeeAttendace A1 INNER JOIN
           EmployeeMaster B1
           ON A1.EmployeeId = B1.Id
      WHERE B1.EmailId in ('raja.xyz@gmail.com')
      ORDER BY A1.Id desc
     )
ORDER BY DayCheckOut DESC
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51745401/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).